# Seeking ArcReader equivalent for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, software-recommendations

I want to share data on a project with many users, and wanted something similar to ArcReader. I like this software as it can be accessed from the server for speed, and therefore updated to other offices periodically.  If there was an option to add layers for users to mark up that would be awesome.

Is there a similar solution or approach for QGIS?

I realize that the users could just use QGIS but was hoping for something so straight forward it could be used virtually straight away.

Answer (score 2):

You can heavily customize QGIS to simplify the interface - we're about to do something similar to open up our mapping to all staff without burdening them with a full-on GIS. Some details here:

[Is it possible and allowed to create a simplified QGIS version with custom interface?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197280/is-it-possible-and-allowed-to-create-a-simplified-qgis-version-with-custom-inter)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the type of data, you can use the qgis plugin qgis2web to create a web map and share that map on server or on your local network.

qgis2web home page
https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web