# Create desktop map explorer application using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, offline

I need to create a map/data-explorer application that works offline (no internet connection), and I am trying to find out if anyone has developed desktop applications with QGIS similar to how one might [develop an offline app using the ArcGIS Runtime SDKs](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/10-2/desktop/guide/create-an-offline-app.htm)?

Comment: you can use QGIS offline with the data locally as is? https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_offline_editing.html

Comment: I need the GUI interface to be much simpler, just a non-editable "explorer" view of the data with minimal point and click and zoom functions. The client is a lawyer presenting the data as part of a court case so simplicity of presentation is of paramount importance.

Comment: then just host it online as a map service... no wifi in the courthouse?

Comment: I think what you are looking at is creating a custom interface. Look at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/197280/is-it-possible-and-allowed-to-create-a-simplified-qgis-version-with-custom-inter

Comment: @NULL.Dude it is a secure facility, so no reliable wifi (this is one of the specfications). I would like to create a custom interface, but the link is dead on that stack exchange post

Comment: Use QGIS2Web to make a locally stored WMS layer in a local directory.  Navigate to the stored location and open the index.html. No internet required, popups can be configured to explore the data, and you can navigate the map as well.